# Leaving and entering the UK past Tier 5 visa end date

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, europe

I'm an American student who will be interning in the UK on a Tier 5 Temporary Worker - Government Authorised Exchange visa for 8 weeks this summer. I was wondering if it would be possible to stay longer to attend my cousin's wedding in Luxembourg exactly one week past the end date listed on my certificate of sponsorship.

I would like to return to the UK after the wedding with the intention of leaving within a day or two. That way I wouldn't have to bring all my luggage for the summer to the wedding. But would I be allowed to re-enter the UK past the end date on my CoS? Or would it be ill-advised to stay in the UK past the end date at all?

Comment: A very good question!

Comment: @Caitlin Have you raised this question with your sponsor? They may well have the expertise and/or contacts to get the authoritative answer on your behalf. Rule 109 of the Tier5 Policy Guidance states that leave to enter automatically lapses once you travel outside the Common Travel Area and you may not automatically be able to re-enter on the basis of your CoS, but the Policy appears to be silent on re-entry as a non visa national https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-application-for-uk-visa-under-tier-5-temporary-worker

Comment: Can you not just enter as a visitor with you American passport and explain the the border guard what you're doing? Sure you'll have proof you've been to a wedding and if you're no longer working you wont need a work visa anymore, just going back home.

Comment: @BritishSam I thought about possibly re-entering as a visitor, but I'm also wondering if I might run into issues at the border since they'll see that I've just finished a temporary work visa and am returning so soon. So, would explaining the wedding situation and being able to prove that I plan on leaving within a few days be enough to allow me back into the UK so soon?

Comment: @Caitlin in my opinion yes, you have a valid reason to re-enter the UK, you'll have proof for everything and I'm guessing your ticket for your flight home. There's no reason for them not to.

Answer (score 1):

While there are circumstances under which you might apply to [extend a Tier 5 visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-government-authorised-exchange/extend-your-visa), it may not be the most effective way to go about remaining in the UK.

It is extremely ill-advised to stay past the end date; it would constitute an overstay in your immigration record and, in future, you would need to apply for a UK visit visa, rather than allowed visa-free entry as a US citizen.

You should leave the UK by the end of your visa validity, as you already plan to do to attend the wedding in Luxembourg. On your return, you present at the border as a US citizen seeking visa-free entry. You may not be asked, but be prepared to explain your plans, to retrieve your belongings and take your flight home.